# UAE e-visa (pink visa)

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, uae

I received an e-visa for a two-month period from a UAE company but I could not travel because I had an ECR passport. I now have an ENCR passport, which has a new number.

Does the company need to change the visa since it shows the old passport number?

Comment: I have one more query I cannot travel with the the old passport along with new passport

How much time it will take to get new visa